# Accessing global variables from inside a function in PHP

Tags: php, global-variables

I want to declare a global variable using PHP and be used inside functions.

I have tried:

```
$var = "something";
function foo()
{
    echo $var;
}
```

yet I receive an error stating that the `$var` is undefined.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The recommended approach would generally be "don't do that", e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$var = "something";
function foo()
{
    global $var;
    echo $var;
}
```

use the term "global" when you need to use variables that were declared outside your function scope.

Answer (score 5):

PHP variables have function scope. I.e., variables inside a function can't be accessed from outside it and global variables can't (by default) be accessed from inside functions. While using the `global` keyword inside functions to im-/export variables is *a* solution, you should not do it. Functions should be self-contained; if you need a value inside a function, [pass it as a parameter](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection), if the function needs to modify global values, `return` them from the function.

Example:

```
function foo($arg)
{
    echo $arg;
}
$var = "something";
foo($var);
```

Please read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @Gordon +1 for additions. But, of course, in the end `global` has won yet again. *sigh*

Comment: @Gordon I think you scared him off with "Dependency Injection", he wanted a little finger and you threw the whole arm at him. ;o)